# Windows XP ruined my Windows 7 bootloader and rescue disc doesn't works, what do I do now?

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, boot, multi-boot, bootloader

I have 3 HDDs, one for Windows 7(x64), the other for Ubuntu(x64 too) and XP, and the 3rd for Ubuntu's SWAP and storage.

XPs bootloader copied itself on top of both 7s and GRUB. No biggie at first, I was able to reinstall GRUB but then I get a NTDLR on Windows 7 and after using 7s disc to repair it the menu says my 7 install is not the same version than the one in the disc, WTF?

Answer (score 3):

You don't say whether or not you can still boot to Windows XP.

If you can indeed boot to Windows XP, you can install the Non Commercial Free version of [EasyBCD](http://neosmart.net/EasyBCD/) to repair/rebuild your bootloader.

Of course, if you can't boot to Windows XP, you can't install a Windows program to repair this.  So, this answer is obviously conditional.

Answer (score 2):

What Umair said.

but since you have dedicated HDD for your OSes here is one trick that i used.

I had a nasty habit of messsing my system (turned out AVG actually sucks), and i had windows and ubuntu running . I had two hdd the larger on had both os and the smaller one was for data and acted as my carry around hdd to move data...

finally i decided to install ubuntu on the smaller one but got stuck with something similar issues.. but then it clicked me.. the os installation scan for other os on all hdd...

so i decided to reinstall windows on my larger drive with the smaller drive absent and install ubuntu with the larger drive removed...

so instead of a grub or some other boot loader i rely on the Bios select boot device...

works like a charm... i still update grub to have an entry for windows but i kept the first boot device as the windows hdd so any guest or my parents got windows and not stuck with some alien virus attacking our pc (actual quote!)

Comment: Yeah I thought of something like that last night after this happened, but I have to fix Win7 first, it wont boot and the install CD refuses to work

Comment: hmmm.... buy a fourth small drive and clonezilla ur os partitions after frrsh installs

Answer (score 2):

First of all Windows 7 needs for booting 3 things:

1. Windows MBR (or any MBR that loads active PBR)
2. Windows 7 PartitionBootRecord on active partition
3. Windows 7 bootmgr and \boot folder (with BCD inside) on active partition

===============

A.

With any partition manager ensure there is one partition on first disk marked ACTIVE.

( if you have a small 100MB partition called "SYSTEM RESERVED" it should be marked as active )

===============

B.

If you can still boot to XP you can try ["Dual-boot repair" tool](http://www.boyans.net)

The tool has a button "Automatic repair". Click it and confirm after that the tool will make your system boot to Windows 7 by default.

================

You should arrange multibooting so that Windows 7 boot manager has control of the multi-booting.
Windows MBR on first disk, Windows 7 boot files on fist disk.

Windows 7 boot manager can boot XP and Ubuntu.

You should have some basic understanding how Win7 is booting and what files are needed.
The same for XP.
The same for Ubuntu.

After that you should understand how Win7 boot manager can boot XP.
And how Win7 can boot Ubuntu/Linux based operating systems.

If you do not have at least basic understanding of how every single operating system boots
troubles with multi booting in the future can be expected to happen again.

Multibooting is not trivial and Windows 8 is comming...